# Is "one" the correct word choice in the following situation?

Tags: word-choice

> The doll would be completely bare if not for her hair---copper red as
>   Tsukiko's dyed **one**---draping her nippleless breasts.

Is one the correct choice here? For some reason, it feels strange to me. But maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing *one* refers to Tsukiko's dyed *hair*, but initially I was confused because I assumed *one* refered to Tsukiko's dyed *doll*.  Although "hair" is (technically) a singular noun, we don't use the pronoun *one* as a substitute for "hair".  "It" is fine, but not "one".

The point of the sentence seems to be to compare the doll's hair to Tsukiko's hair, in which case it might have been better to repeat the noun:

> The doll would be completely bare if not for her hair -- the same copper red as Tsukiko's dyed hair -- draping her nippleless breasts.

As a point of style, I don't like the word "dyed" here.  It may be accurate that her hair is not naturally that color, but it breaks the *flow* of the sentence.  I would instead say:

> The doll would be completely bare if not for her hair -- copper red like Tsukiko's -- draping her nippleless breasts.